# First chapter after List of Tables starts on page 2, should be 1

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

My LOT spans two pages - one is numbered ix the other 1. The first chapter starts with page number 2. I would like my first chapter to start with page number 1.

So my contents page looks like this

**Contents**

*List of Figures .......... viii*

*List of Tables ............. ix*

*Introduction ................ 2*

*Aims & Objectives ............7*

and so on..........

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\blindtext

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\blinddocument

\begin{figure}
Foo bar
\caption{My figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{My table}
Foo bar
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, deleting all the lines that are not needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I turned your code into somewhat of an MWE -- we don't have you /Chapter .tex files, so we couldn't compile that; and as far as I can see, all these packages were not relevant for your problem. Please see if the MWE still reflects your problem, and adapt it if necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was my first question. Thanks @doncherry for creating a MWE which reflected my problem aptly.

Comment: @ManojAravind: No problem, we're here to help `:)`. tex.sx is somewhat different from other places to find help on the web, we prefer our special question & answer format, and new users have to get used to it. You'll see the advantages of this format when you're browsing through other users' questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
\clearpage
```

after your `\listoftables` and

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

just before your first chapter.

Comment: Just `\clearpage` would suffice, since `\pagenumbering{arabic}` resets the page counter to start from 1.

Comment: As @Werner suggested using just \clearpage helped to reset the first chapter to begin with 1.