# Page Numbering After List of Tables

Tags: page-numbering, clearpage

First of all I looked for a solution, but couldn't find one. Even though I got similar question.
But none of the solution worked for me.
[Link 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79869/first-chapter-after-list-of-tables-starts-on-page-2-should-be-1)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\linespread{1.4}



\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\input{TitlePage}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\input{certificate}
\input{projectapprovalsheet
\input{abstract}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{ack}
\input{tableofcontents} 

\input{listoffigures}
\input{listoftables}
\newpage   //here is the problem
\cleardoublepage  //as per the solution I got
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{1}    //as per the solution
\input{chap1}
\end{document}
```

But still I get a blank page and the First Chapter starts from Page 2[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Do you really use `\input{tableofcontents}` to create a table of contents? Apart from that, we can't test your code as you input a lot of files that we don't have access to. Could you therefor please edit your example to make it self-contained?

Comment: Yes I will make it self contained. and I am a very newbie in Latex. Please help me out @leandriis, Also i Changed the `\input{listoftables}` to `\listoftables` still no effect

Answer (score 2):

This works for me giving no blank page after the LoT and the first chapter starting on page 1.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
TITLE STUFF ETC
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{First}
Some text.
\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table}
TABLE
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, if you use the `twoside` option `\documentclass[twoside]{report}` then the above may give a blank page between the LoT (roman page numbers) and the first chapter (arabic page number 1).

Comment: It did not solve my issue. Also, I am using `\include{chaptername}` to start chapters.

Comment: @SiddhantGhosh In your MWE you used `\input` not `\include`.  Is there anything else that you haven't revealed to us. In any case my answer worked for me even when I changed the inline code for chapters to use `\include{achapter}`. I have no idea what might be in your `\include{chaptername}`; perhaps code in there is causing your problem. GOM goodbye.

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` is what worked for me!